# Dynamic xquery/xpath in activevos

Tags: xpath, xquery

I want to configure xpath or xquery in property file and need to use that variable while reading data.

for example,  I configured `xquery` property in configuration file like

```
aXquery = types:Request/types:Person/type:details/type:a/text()
```

I need to use this `aXquery` variable in script some thing like

```
$RESTRequest/types:payload/string($configData/ns2:XPaths/ns2:aXquery)
```

Can anyone help me on this how to do in activevos?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can use property files directly. AFAIK there are three options to implement a dynamic configuration mechanism:

1. Use URN Mappings (Configurable in ActiveVOS Console / Administration / URN Mappings). You can read those with functions available in XQuery in ActiveVOS (resolveURN).
2. Place the configuration value in the database (e.g. create a new table) and read those with ActiveVOS DB access mechanisms.
3. Wrap your config file in a Web service and call the service from your process.